# Как вывести данные по ключу объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. Нужно сделать вывод данных по ключу со всех объектов, дело в том, что ключ который вводишь есть, значение у ключа тоже есть, а выводит `underfined`.

```js
var array = [
  {name: 'vlad', age: 5},
  {name: 'max', age: 3},
  {name: 'anton', age: 7}
]

var userkey = prompt('По какому ключу ищем?');

function checkKey() {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(userkey in array[i]) {
      document.write(array[i].userkey + '<br />');
    }
  }
};

checkKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должно работать.

```js
var array = [
  {name: 'vlad', age: 5},
  {name: 'max', age: 3},
  {name: 'anton', age: 7}
]

var userkey = prompt('По какому ключу ищем?');

function checkKey() {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(userkey in array[i]) {
      document.write(array[i][userkey] + '<br />');
    }
  }
};

checkKey();
```